# Cannot disable tap toggling of Fixed Headers in JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I´m developing a web app with JQuery Mobile (version 1.3.0). It uses a fixed header but I cannot disable the "tap toggling" behavior when the user taps the form contents.

I´ve tried to use the property "data-tap-toggle=false" but it doesn´t work. The header continues to be hidden when the user taps the form and displayed when taps again.

Thanks in advance!

```html
<div data-role="page" class="Page" id="parameter_page">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
        <div class="headerContainer" >
            <a href="index.html"      data-role="button" class="ui-btn-left"  data-inline="true" data-direction="reverse" data-icon="back"  >Voltar</a>
            <a href="instrucoes.html" data-role="button" class="ui-btn-right" data-inline="true" >Instruções</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    ...
    ...
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: hmmm..I guess I got you wrong. You need to disable the header and footer, and then trigger full screen?

Comment: Having the same problem.  Ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

First, in order to utilize `data-tap-toggle` you have to added `data-fullscreen="true"` and `data-position="fixed"` to both *Header* and *Footer*. `data-tap-toggle` isn't necessary now, since you control them dynamically.

Then control them this way.

```
$("[data-role=header],[data-role=footer]").fixedtoolbar({ tapToggle: true });

$("[data-role=header],[data-role=footer]").fixedtoolbar({ fullscreen: true });
```

On tap or click, both will appear and then disappear.

Test it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Pf4ca/).

I hope I have been of help.